# Laravel job marked as failed, exception saying too many attempts but the job was successful?

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I am working with laravel v5.3.30 and I have complex job which is doing guzzle requests and importing data into the system. If I multiple workers with multiple tries I am getting double, even triple insertions into my database. This is what the job looks like overview:

```
<?php

namespace Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Uppdragshuset\AO\Tenant\Import\ImportHandler;

class ImportPatentCreateCaseJob implements ShouldQueue
{

    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $number;
    protected $import;
    protected $workflow_id;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($number, $import, $workflow_id)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->import = $import;
        $this->workflow_id = $workflow_id;

        $this->onQueue('import');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $importHandler = new ImportHandler();

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $patent = $importHandler->checkIfPatentExists($this->number['number']);

            if( ! $patent){
                $patent = $importHandler->handlePatentData($this->number);
            }

            if( ! $importHandler->checkIfCaseExists($patent->id, $this->workflow_id)){
                $task_id = $importHandler->prepareWorkflowAndGetTaskId($this->workflow_id);
                $importHandler->createCase($this->workflow_id, $task_id, $patent->id);
            }

            $this->import->update([
                'status' => 'COMPLETED'
            ]);
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            Log::error($e->getTraceAsString());
            DB::rollBack();
            $this->import->update([
                'status' => 'FAILED'
            ]);
        }

        $importHandler->markBatchAsCompleted($this->import);
    }
}
```

I am checking if the data already exists and if it does it should not import it again. I have even wrapped the whole code in a try catch statement so even if something fails, it would log it and the job would run fine.

When I tried with a `tries=1`, 55 jobs were created, out of which 7 failed but my failed-jobs table shows me 30 rows in there.

So I don't understand how jobs are failing even though I am handling the exceptions. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

push job to queue without workers and process this job manualy